# Python: average value for timedelta after dataframe grouping

Tags: python, pandas, average, aggregation, timedelta

I know, it is very popular question and there are tons of topics about average fo timedelta and datetime arguments. Unfortunately, i am stuck with my approach and would like to ask your assistance with task below:

as result of line:

```
time_to_rent = user_payments[user_payments.rentComplete].groupby(['rentId','creditCardId','rentComplete'], as_index=False).agg({'createdAt': np.min, 'updatedAt': np.max})
```

I got the dataframe (in dict format):

```
time_to_rent = {'rentId': {0: 43.0, 1: 87.0, 2: 140.0, 3: 454.0, 4: 1458.0}, 'creditCardId': {0: 40, 1: 40, 2: 40, 3: 40, 4: 40}, 'rentComplete': {0: True, 1: True, 2: True, 3: True, 4: False}, 'createdAt': {0: Timestamp('2020-08-24 16:13:11.850216'), 1: Timestamp('2020-09-10 10:47:31.748628'), 2: Timestamp('2020-09-13 15:29:06.077622'), 3: Timestamp('2020-09-24 08:08:39.852348'), 4: Timestamp('2020-10-19 08:54:09.891518')}, 'updatedAt': {0: Timestamp('2020-08-24 20:26:31.805939'), 1: Timestamp('2020-09-10 20:05:18.759421'), 2: Timestamp('2020-09-13 18:38:10.044112'), 3: Timestamp('2020-09-24 08:53:22.512533'), 4: Timestamp('2020-10-19 09:24:03.982986')}, 'rent_time': {0: Timedelta('0 days 04:13:19.955723'), 1: Timedelta('0 days 09:17:47.010793'), 2: Timedelta('0 days 03:09:03.966490'), 3: Timedelta('0 days 00:44:42.660185'), 4: Timedelta('0 days 00:29:54.091468')}}
```

then i am adding one more column:

```
time_to_rent['rent_time'] = time_to_rent['updatedAt'] - time_to_rent['createdAt']
```

i would like to group time_to_rent by "creditCardId" and have average value for "rent_time" column.

That code returns error back:

```
average_per_user = time_to_rent.groupby('creditCardId').agg({'rent_time' : np.mean})
```

And here is the error back:

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _cython_agg_general(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
    906 
    907         if len(output) == 0:
--> 908             raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")
    909 
    910         return self._wrap_aggregated_output(output)

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

not sure why len(output) equals 0 ...

Comment: What is error here?

Comment: There is a ")" missing at the end of your line.

Comment: yes, my mistype.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to exclude `False` values from `df.rentComplete` (and close the whole thing with `)`).  Filtering with a boolean column is simple in Pandas:

```
average_per_user = time_to_rent[time_to_rent.rentComplete] \
    .groupby('creditCardId').agg({'rent_time' : np.mean})
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks like my problem isn't in agg param, but in strange values in "creditCardId" column: here is the error: DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
average_per_user = time_to_rent.groupby('creditCardId').mean()['rent_time']
```

Comment: thanks, but doesn't work: DataError: No numeric types to aggregate.
It strange... I left only average_per_user = time_to_rent.groupby('creditCardId') and got back: <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000000000B596790> when i printed average_per_user

Comment: try: `average_per_user = time_to_rent.groupby('creditCardId').mean()`

Comment: also please attach the output

Comment: I updated the question above. Looks like the probme isn't in .mean(). No argument 'creditCardId' in the dataframe.

Comment: can you please forward me the df in dict format let me attach a complete solution

Comment: {'createdAt': {(43.0, 40, True): Timestamp('2020-08-24 16:13:11.850216'), (87.0, 40, True): Timestamp('2020-09-10 10:47:31.748628'), (140.0, 40, True): Timestamp('2020-09-13 15:29:06.077622'), (454.0, 40, True): Timestamp('2020-09-24 08:08:39.852348'), (1458.0, 40, False): Timestamp('2020-10-19 08:54:09.891518')}, 'updatedAt': {(43.0, 40, True): Timestamp('2020-08-24 20:26:31.805939'), (87.0, 40, True): Timestamp('2020-09-10 20:05:18.759421'), (140.0, 40, True): Timestamp('2020-09-13 18:38:10.044112'),

Comment: (454.0, 40, True): Timestamp('2020-09-24 08:53:22.512533'), (1458.0, 40, False): Timestamp('2020-10-19 09:24:03.982986')}} - it is the rest of the dict

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223291/discussion-between-divyessh-and-ocmarus).